# Add additional charge to PayPal payment button

Tags: api, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-ipn

We have attached a PayPal $4 button in our web application. Now we are planning to add addition charge based on location. So What is the best possibility of add the additional charge to the PayPal check out ? Can I add additional charge to fixed PayPal payment button ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the type of PayPal button/integration you are using.

- If it is a PayPal button rendered using [the JS SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), then you can add an [onShippingChange function](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/shipping-options/) that calculates a new total based on the selected address.
- If it is one of the old "Buy Now" or "Add to Cart" HTML form yellow pill buttons, you can [create a shipping profile](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/ProfileAndTools/#calculate-shipping-charges-automatically) in the PayPal account.
- For other integration types, the web system/cart software communicating with PayPal will need to calculate and change the total after the address is determined.